# Conditions within an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, conditional-statements

I have a great couple of variables named `$value1`, `$value2` etc. I want to create an array *key* for each variable only if the variable is not empty. Something like this:

```
$array = array(
    If (!empty($value1)) { "bar" => "foo", }
    If (!empty($value2)) { "foo" => "bar", }
);
```

How do I do this and what would be good practice?

Comment: Do you want to create an array key as the _contents_ of each of those variables? How do `foo/bar` relate above?

Comment: How many variables do you have? If just a few, what you have is fine. If you have several, collect them into an array and loop over them.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski That was just an example. To clarify, if $value1 is empty, then there shouldn't be a key created.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693754/how-can-i-add-a-condition-inside-a-php-array

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Can you please post an answer detailing exactly how I would collect my variables into an array and loop over them? It seems this is the best practice?

Comment: @HenrikPetterson That array suggestion was before we understood what your need actually was. Since there's no tight relationship between the variable values and the array keys, the answers you got look like they're sufficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP arrays are dynamic, so you can add stuff to it easily:

```
$array = array(); // start with empty one

if (!empty($value1)) $array['bar'] = 'foo';
if (!empty($value2)) $array['foo'] = 'bar';

// you don't even have to specify a key, 
// it will just increment accordingly if left out
if (!empty($value3)) $array[] = 'foobar';
```

this will result in (if all 3 vars are non-empty):

```
array(3) {
  'a' => 'foo',
  'b' => 'bar',
  0   => 'foobar'
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying

Comment: I have one final question if you don't mind. How do I use this approach with an indexed array? array(value1,value2,value3,etc.);

Comment: How do I add a new value to the array?

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Using the `[]` empty square bracket syntax. `if (!empty($value1)) $array[] = $value1;`  http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying

Comment: I'll add it for completeness

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it that way - if you use the array shortcut notation, you WILL create an entry in the array, whether there's a value or not. You'll have to test/set each key individually:

```
$arr = array();
if (!empty($value)) { $arr['bar'] = 'foo' }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use [Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
$array = array();
$count = 4; //You can have n variables
for($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++){
    if(isset(${'value' . $i})){
      $array[$i] = ${'value' . $i};
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't resemble anything in the question.

Comment: Before downvoting, read the question: _I have a great couple of variables named $value1, $value2. etc_

Comment: you aren't even testing if the variables exist... and I'm pretty sure those variable names were just examples.

Comment: Fixed the check. You're pretty sure but not enough.