# PHP array with with If Empty statement, separated by coma

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, if-statement, conditional-statements

So I put together this address format array and it works really well:

```
$address_street = get_field( 'address_street' );
$address_city = get_field( 'address_city' );
$address_postcode = get_field( 'address_postcode' );
$address_state = get_field( 'address_state' ); 
$terms = get_the_terms($post->id, 'address_country');

foreach ( $terms as $term ) { }
?>

<div id="address-widget">
    <p><strong>Where to find us?</strong></p> 

    <?php $arr = array($address_street, $address_city, $address_postcode, $address_state, $term->name); ?>

    <p class="address-format">
        <?php echo implode(", ", $arr); ?>
    </p>
</div>
```

and it outputs all the details of the address separated by coma, just like I wanted.

The problem now is that `$address_street, $address_postcode and $address_state` are not compulsory fields, so if they are not filled in, that they would be left blank without the extra coma.

So I can find how to input the array with items that are conditional here: [How can I add a condition inside a php array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693754/how-can-i-add-a-condition-inside-a-php-array), but how do I add the condition inside the array, leave the blanks out and have the filled out elements separated by coma in the same time?

So if only the compulsory fields (city, country) are filled in, I would get output like this: ***City, Country***

Comment: Your code has several errors... Like  `<?php }?>` should be `<?php } ?>` , you are using `$term` after closing `foreach` which makes no sense and an open and close curly braces `$arr = array($address_street, $address_city, $address_postcode, $address_state, $term->name); {  //something }` without anything written or condition....

Comment: Thanks Praveen, fixed now ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got you right the solution is probably simpler than you think. What you want is to print all the array values (if they are not empty) in a comma separated string. What you can do to achieve this is to simply remove empty elements from the array when printing:

```
<?php echo implode(", ", array_filter($arr)); ?>
```

This will remove empty elements from the array before imploding it into a comma separated string.

Comment: I didn't think it will be that simple, but it works absolutely great!! Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

if(get_field( 'address_street' ) != ''){

$address_street = get_field( 'address_street' );
}

if(get_field( 'address_city' ) != ''){

$address_city = get_field( 'address_city' );
}

if(get_field( 'address_postcode' ) != ''){

$address_postcode = get_field( 'address_postcode' );
}

if(get_field( 'address_state' ) != ''){

$address_state = get_field( 'address_state' ); 
}

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove the empty values from the array before the implode using:

```
$arr = array_filter($arr);
```

See more about the [array_filter()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function.