# How can I add an if condition to a html::img helper?

Tags: php, yii2, frameworks

How can I add an `if` condition to a `html::img` helper? How can I add a class by `if` condition to an Yii2 image?

Comment: What have you tried already?  If possible, please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add a condition inside a php array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693754/how-can-i-add-a-condition-inside-a-php-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ternary operator :

```
<?= Html::img(
       'Image Location',
       [
          'class' => (condition) ? 'class-true' : 'class-false',
          'alt' => 'Image',
       ]
) ?>
```